# Trying to understand importing modules in ghci using cabal

Tags: haskell

I've recently begin learning to code in Haskell -- in general all is going well, but one irritation that repeatedly rears its head is ghci not recognizing modules on hackage when I try to use them.

Some modules work fine -- [Data.List.subsequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List.html) (for example) returns all sublists of a list as desired:

[image]

Others seem more problematic -- [Data.NumberLength](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/number-length-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-NumberLength.html) goes completely unrecognized:

[image]

I haven't explicitly downloaded or installed anything in terms of modules, but my (rudimentary) understanding from the [GHCup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/) home page together with the [introduction from Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/introduction) is that ghci can handle fetching and importing any modules I need for the code I try to write.

What am I doing wrong here?